# Porque JOptionPane me da NAN al sacar la raíz de 2 grado

Tags: java, java-swing, math

Estoy Intentando crear un programa en java que resuelva ecuaciones de 2 grado, pero al mostrar el resultado de la operación aun no he hallado la respuesta, agradecería su ayuda. El código es el siguiente:

```
package ejercicio7ecuaciones;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Ejercicio7Ecuaciones {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vamos a calcular las raices de la ecuacion, por favor, ingrese los valores");

    double a,b,c, resultado1, resultado2;


    a = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el valor de a"));
    b = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el valor de b"));
    c = Double.parseDouble (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el valor de c"));

    // Calculos

    resultado1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2) - 4 *a * c));
    resultado2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2) - 4 *a * c));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El resultado positivo es: " + resultado1);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El resultado negativo es: " + resultado2);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código está bien, el problema es en la ecuación de segundo grado.
Te falta cambiar el **"+"** por un **"-"** en el **resultado2** y añadirle a ambas la **división entre "2*a"**.

```
resultado1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2) - (4*a*c)))/(2*a);
resultado2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2) - (4*a*c)))/(2*a);
```